# Radio buttons using razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view that has a radio button group on it.  The radio button really has nothing to do with my model.  It just decides what path the code will take (what stored procedure to call based on what selection they made).  How do I get the selection value to the controller?

Something like this:

```
<p>
    Select the option describing what you want to do:
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("selectProcess", "NewLetter", new { @id = "NewLetter" })Create a New Letter</label>
    <br />
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("selectProcess", "LetterInProgress", new { @id = "LetterInProgress" })Edit a Letter in Progress</label>
    <br/>
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("selectProcess", "GeneratedLetter", new { @id = "GeneratedLetter" })Edit a Letter that has been Generated</label>
    <br/>
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("selectProcess", "AppendGeneratedLetter", new { @id = "AppenGeneratedLetter" })Append a Generated Letter</label>

    <input type="submit" value="Go" />

</p>
```

Not sure if I need these id's in here, but I just want to have a method in my controller that receives the selected value and calls one stored procedure or another (as part of my model)...the selected options do not represent a field in the model.

I'm not a good front-end person, so I know I might be going about this backward.

Comment: You should be using a view model with a property `selectProcess` and post back the view model. Otherwise you will need to access the value using `Request["selectProcess"]`. And yes you should give the radio buttons and `id` attribute to avoid invalid html (without them, the `RadioButton()` method will generate all radio buttons with `id="selectProcess"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the HTML inside a form and post it to your controller as you would with any other data you wanted to pass back to the server.

```
<form action="/Controller/HandlePost" method="post">
    <p>                                                         <!-- trimmed for clarity -->
        Select the option describing what you want to do:
        <br/>
        <label>@Html.RadioButton("selectProcess", "NewLetter", new { @id = "NewLetter" })Create a New Letter</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </p>
</form>
```

On the server side, use the `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` around the action to only accept post, then redirect back to an action with a view afterwards to clear the post data.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult HandlePost
{
    string selectProcess = Request.Form("selectProcess");

    // process selectProcess data however you need

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

If for whatever reason you have a single controller which both handles post data and returns the view if accessed via get, you can do this:

```
public ActionResult Index
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod.ToString() == "POST")
    {
        // handle POST data
        string selectProcess = Request.Form("selectProcess");
        // process selectProcess data however you need
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    // handle GET view
    return View();
}
```

The redirect inside the POST section is still required to allow the browser to be refreshed and the back history to work without resending the post data.

Obviously, Controller, HandlePost, Home, Index etc. to be replaced with your controller and action names.

---

As @Stephen Muecke mentions in the comments, it's good practice to give radio buttons id's when using the `RadioButton()` method to avoid invalid HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips.  I found I just had to just look at the Request["selectProcess"] in my ActionResult SelectProcess() method that was marked with the attribute [HttpPost]